# How can I not return HttpURLConnection InputStream before task is done?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, asynchronous, inputstream

Here's what I'm trying to do (in order):

Program A)

1) Send a HTTP request to a servlet

5) Receive the response

Program B)

2) Receive the HTTP call

3) Do some tasks

4) Write to the outputStream

Here's my (non-working) code :

Program A :

```
        URL url = new URL(targetURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true); // this is to enable writing
        conn.setDoInput(true); // this is to enable reading
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();

        out.write("blabla".getBytes());

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

Program B :

```
 @WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        TestRunnable r= new TestRunnable(req,resp);
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

The problem here is that, since the tasks are processed in the thread, service( ) returns directly and thus program A retrieve automatically the InputStream.
I'd like to wait for the thread to end and then return the InputStream;
I could do the tasks directly in the service( ) method but it would be blocking and I don't want that.

The more I think about it, the more I think it is impossible to achieve.

Can someone help me, or tell me why I'm wrong trying to achieve this ?

Comment: Don't run r in a Thread. Just do r.run();

Comment: You need to set `asyncSupported=true` in your Servlet and use an [`AsyncContext`](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/swchan2/archive/2014/05/21/server-sent-events-async-servlet-example).

Answer (score -1):

Servlets are already multithreaded, in your case there is no reason to launch a thread to do the service.

Just call the run method of your runnable directly without constructing a `Thread` with `r.run()`, or call `t.join()` to wait until the end of the thread.

Comment: No. This is not the answer to the question. This is an answer to another question, on how to turn an asynchronous task into a synchronous one. Which I am not sure why you would want to do. There are 1,000 reasons (at least) why the OP might want to run a ask on a thread that isn't an HTTP worker thread. I would start by reading [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3) and then maybe read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html).